# server 2012 how to check if asp.net register valid or not?

Tags: asp.net, aspnet-regiis.exe

I want to register asp.net to my server 2012, then I check by using aspnet_regiis.exe -lv, it return the result below, it didn't state is valid or not.. then it's means register successful on the server or not?

4.0.30319.0             C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll
1.1.4322.0              C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\aspnet_isapi.dll
4.0.30319.0             C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll

this is when I check on my own pc, it should have the status of Valid..
1.1.4322.0      Valid           C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\aspnet_isapi.dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you did not see the 'valid' status when you run the 'aspnet_regiis.exe -lv' , another way is to check the registry to make sure it is installed and enabled.

https://help.upcurvecloud.com/wmobile/howto_verify_aspnet_installed.html

regards.